# undefined method for ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :medicalhistory 
end
```

Mdedicalhistory model

```
class Medicalhistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user #foreign key -> user_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

**Error**

```
undefined method `lastname' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb6ad89d0>


#this works
@medicalhistory = Medicalhistory.find(current_user.id) 
print   "\n" + @medicalhistory.lastname

#this doesn't!
@medicalhistory = Medicalhistory.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)
print   "\n" + @medicalhistory.lastname #error on this line
```

Comment: Does `@medicalhistory.first.lastname` work?

Comment: not sure if this is "best practice", but 
@medicalhistory = Medicalhistory.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)[0]
should work

Comment: as a noob, using `find` instead of `where` fixed the issues for me

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Well, you are getting back an object of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not your model instance, thus the error since there is no method called `lastname` in `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Doing `@medicalhistory.first.lastname` works because `@medicalhistory.first` is returning the first instance of the model that was found by the `where`.

Also, you can print out `@medicalhistory.class` for both the working and "erroring" code and see how they are different.

Comment: Thanks, I missed `first` method when looking at the API.

Answer (score 6):

One other thing to note, `:medicalhistory` should be plural as it is a `has_many` relationship

So your code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :medicalhistory 
end
```

Should be written:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :medicalhistories 
end
```

From the Rails docs ([found here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association))

> The name of the other model is pluralized when declaring a has_many
>   association.

This is because rails automatically infers the class name from the association name.

If a user only `had_one` `medicalhistory` this would be singular as you had written:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :medicalhistory 
end
```

I know you already accepted an answer, but thought this would help reduce further errors/confusion.