# Not able to get url from uploaded image, undefined method `url' error on has_many associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, rails-activerecord

```
undefined method `url' for #<GalleryPhoto:0x007f80c05a4ba8>

10:   <%= @gallery.date %>
11: </p>
12: 
13: <%= @gallery.gallery_photos.first.url %>
14: 
15: 
16: <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_gallery_path(@gallery) %>
```

I am attempting to create a photo album system in a rails app where albums are created and images are uploaded to it via paperclip.  I am unable to get the .url method to work on my show page to display the image.  The way it is set up is like this:

Gallery Model (has many gallery_photos)

GalleryPhotos Model(belongs_to gallery)

gallery show:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Gallery name:</b>
  <%= @gallery.gallery_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Date:</b>
  <%= @gallery.date %>
</p>

<%= @gallery.gallery_photos.first.url %>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_gallery_path(@gallery) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', galleries_path %>
```

gallery model

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :date, :gallery_name, :gallery_photos_attributes
    has_many :gallery_photos, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery_photos

end
```

gallery_photo model

```
class GalleryPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :photo, :caption, :date, :gallery_id

    belongs_to :gallery

    has_attached_file :photo,:styles => { :large => "300x300<", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

end
```

Gallery controller

```
  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
    @gallery.gallery_photos.build # added this
  end

  def show
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @gallery = Gallery.new(params[:gallery])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.save!
        format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @gallery, status: :created, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The table is mysql, and I am running this through a vagrant virtual system.  It is inserting on new, and it is making it. On new it is inserting data into the table for the galleries and for gallery_photos.  No matter what I do, I cannot get a url out of it.

Comment: dont you need  image_tag? so <%= image_tag gallery_photo.url(:thumb) %>

Comment: I do need an image tag once @gallery.gallery_photos.first.url actually gives a url.

Comment: This question is very similar, almost too similar... but the fix they have I'm already using. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004891/undefined-method-for-activerecordrelation

Comment: ok so what happens when you try this <%= image_tag(gallery_photo.url(:thumb)) %> and how many photos are you trying to render?

Comment: or it could be something like this <% for photo in @gallery_photo.photos %>
       <%= image_tag(photo.avatar.url(:thumb)) %>
      <% end %>

Comment: I just want to get one to show up, will add more from there. I entered in the loop thing, its a better implementation anyways.  Gets the same error:
undefined method `url' for #<GalleryPhoto:0x0000000292d568>

Comment: `@gallery.gallery_photos.first.photo.url`, since `url` belongs to `:photo`?

Comment: @Sunxperous yeap, that did that trick, thanks a bunch!  That is the issue.

Comment: good spot  @Sunxperous

Comment: @Sunxperous you may post the answer as an actual answer. Probably Tommy is happy to accept your answer and give you your well-deserved reputation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip, the `url` method belongs to
`has_attached_file :photo`, so the correct way to retrieve the url is

```
@gallery.gallery_photos.first.photo.url
```