# Rails 4 has_many_through controllers and view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I've confirmed my has many through relationship is working via the terminal as I've created a relationship and it shows in my database. My question is centered on making changes specifically regarding the view and controllers themselves which I haven't found many specific answers towards. For instance in pit index.html.erb I get this error

```
undefined method `users' for #<Pit::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000106230df0>
```

for this bit of markup below

```
<p>Pit Created by: <%= link_to  @pit.users, pit.user %> on <%= pit.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y") %></p>
```

I currently have in my pits controller this -

```
def index
  if params[:tag]
  @pit = Pit.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
  @pits = Pit.paginate(page: params[:page])
else
  @pit = Pit.all
  @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
  @pits = Pit.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
end
```

My models consist of this

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
  has_many :joinables
  has_many :pits, :through => :joinables
  has_many :comments
  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?
```

Pit

```
class Pit < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :topic, :author, :summary, presence: true
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_votable
  has_many :comments
  has_many :joinables
  has_many :users, :through => :joinables
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader


class Joinable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pit
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I know this is probably easy but I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly to change without breaking anything. Do I need to add another instance variable in my def index or something? I know I'm close, I just need a bit of direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to remove anything specific to your app when you google an error message. For example, googling "undefined method for activerecord::relation" turned up [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004891/undefined-method-for-activerecordrelation), which should answer your question.

Comment: Didn't consider that David, Thanks. Will definitely do.

Answer (score 0):

Since `tagged_with` returns many records, you need to add `.first` to your 'tagged_with()' calls:

```
  @pit = Pit.tagged_with(params[:tag]).first
```

...or iterate over the pit records, if that's your intent.

BTW -- Since `find_by` only returns one record, that's why you didn't need `.first` there, in case you were confused.